# Do console.log of native methods and properties

Tags: javascript

How can I print in the console, native properties and methods? Like for example, I have an array and I want to know all native functions like: sort(), shift(), pop()... etc, without need to research the JS library. And the console must return these methods.

Comment: Are you asking how to see all array methods or all native functions in general? Do you also want web API functions etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can press F12, go to console and type in for example `console.log(Array.prototype)`

Same you can do with `String, Object, Number`

[image]

Comment: There is any way? without need to attach the js code to a HTML file? Because I like to study js files only, running in the shell  attaching in package,json using yarn start

Comment: you want only to use js without the need of an html file and browser?  then just install node.js on your computer. after you installed it , i would strongly recommend, to use visual studio code. then you open some folder, create an file for example `test.js` and then you open the terminal, or with the key CTRL + SHIFT + Ö in my case then you can simply write `node test.js` and it will run your js code in a shell

Comment: I hope you mean something like this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial but first you will need to install node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype` have all the information.

```
console.log(Array.prototype);
```